# Rename ASP.NET_SessionId without changing Web.Config

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-config, session-state

Usually Web.Config settings can be changed in the C# code. Is there any way to change the ASP.NET_SessionId without manipulating the Web.Config?

Comment: This sounds like an X Y Problem: why do you want to change that value without changing web.config?

Comment: @Richard Company policy says we cannot manipulate the session state in web.configs.